# play video screen off

Tags: android

I wish to play video when the device screen is off. what could be the strategy here.

I have found out that i may need a receiver which handles intent
ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and ACTION_SCREEN_ON

If the screen is off, i would need to acquire a wakelock like this.

```
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_LOCK|ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "my tag");   
wl.acquire();
```

Then probably play the video.

Can someone throw more light on this.

regards

Comment: U need to acquire SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKELOCK even if the screen is ON, as it will assure screen will not turn OFF till ur application ends. U need not use aquire cause wakeup that time.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the update. It worked for me.